# navigateInSytemBrowser for HTMLLoader in Flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am working on Flex 4.5 SDK and using Flash Builder 4 IDE for my Flex/AIR Desktop Application.

In my project I want to load one html page in one of the canvas areas. I am using HTMlLoader to load my page. My web page loads successfully in the canvas area.

The problem is that when I click on the links embeded in the html page that I have loaded, they do not open in my browser window.

There is a property of HTMlLoader "navigateInSystemBrowser" which need to be set to true to allow the embeded links of the page to open in a default browser window. But this property works only in Flex 4.0 I tried running the same thing a sample project using Flex 4.0 as the SDK and it works perfectly fine. But when I work with Flex 4.5 SDK it does not works.

Please suggest if there any other workaround to achieve this.

Thanks,
Nitika

Answer (score 1):

Flex 4.5 SDK have some rough edges, it's still in beta, so maybe it's not a wise decision to use it yet. Few days ago had similar issue, embedded resources didn't worked in Flex Hero SDK, but they were working in 4.1. After I almost gave up decided to try latest night build and so far it's working, tho strange longer compilation times are now my issue.

So first you may try latest 4.5 SDK, if not you should fall back to 4.1, unless you are depending on 4.5 features.